# How to fix "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in..."

Tags: php

This error appear when I execute this code. I don't know what to do. Please help

```
<?php

$Q = strtoupper($_GET['q']);
$q = ucwords($_GET['q']); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT src FROM mytable WHERE '%$Q%' NOT LIKE 0 OR SRC LIKE '%$Q%'");

$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$numRows = function() 
{
    if($total <= 4){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return ($total / 4);
    }
};
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>              
    <h2>Resultados para la búsqueda <?php echo "$q"?></h2>
    <h3>Número de resultados total: <?php echo "$total"?></h3>
<?php  
}
```

Comment: Before going to production, I highly recommend you switch to `PDO` for your database operations. [Here is a tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). The problem here is that you're using $_GET values, which end-users could manipulate. The least you could do is [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), but `PDO`'s prepared statements are significantly more secure. `mysqli` has prepared statements, but they're harder to work with because they use unnamed placeholders whereas PDO lets you name your placeholders, making it easier to use.

Comment: Why do you have `$numRows = function()` - this would be much clearer to be done as inline code rather than using a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the error, it sounds like you're using `$numRows` as a string, but that must be farther down in your code, something you haven't posted. You can do `$numRows()`, I believe, to invoke the function, but inside `$numRows`, you use `$total`. As Zain Farooq suggested, you may `use ($total)` but it may be better to pass the `$total` as an argument of the function call. Example:

```php
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$getNumRows = function($tot) 
{
    if($tot <= 4){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return ($tot / 4);
    }
};
$result = $getNumRows($total);
echo "I have {$result} rows.";
```

What I think you are doing, somewhere is doing something like `echo $numRows`, but it needs to be `echo $numRows()`, so the function is being called.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies here

```
$numRows = (function() use ($total) {
if($total <= 4){
return 1;
}else{
 return ($total / 4);
}
})();
```

You must wrap function between parantheses and if you want to pass the parameter you should use `use()`